# ASP\VB.NET checkbox state not updated in code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is a simplified version of the issue I'm having but it should highlight what's going on.  I have three checkboxes, one is disabled and is only checked if the first two are checked.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb1" runat="server" Text="text1" OnClick="CheckClick();"></asp:CheckBox>
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb2" runat="server" Text="text2" OnClick="CheckClick();"></asp:CheckBox>
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb3" runat="server" Text="text3" Enabled="False"></asp:CheckBox>
```

The states of the boxes are initialized from a database and assigned in the vb code behind like so.

```
Private Sub PopulateCheckBoxes(ByRef cb1DataBaseVal As Boolean, ByRef cb2DataBaseVal As Boolean _
                                ,ByRef cb3DataBaseVal As Boolean)

    cb1.Checked = cb1DataBaseVal
    cb2.Checked = cb2DataBaseVal
    cb3.Checked = cb3DataBaseVal

End Sub
```

Their behavior is controlled by a java script in the same .aspx file where they are declared.

```
function CheckClick(){
    m_cb1 = $get('<%= cb1.ClientID%>');
    m_cb2 = $get('<%= cb2.ClientID%>');
    m_cb3 = $get('<%= cb3.ClientID%>');

    if (m_cb1.checked == true && m_cb2.checked == true){
        m_cb3.checked = true;
    }
    else{ 
        m_cb3.checked = false;
    }
}
```

On page save the code behind reads the checked state of the elements and saves them back to the database.

```
Private Sub SaveCheckBoxes()

    cb1DataBaseReturn = cb1.Checked
    cb2DataBaseReturn = cb2.Checked
    cb3DataBaseReturn = cb3.Checked

    SendToDatabase(cb1DataBaseReturn , cb2DataBaseReturn , cb3DataBaseReturn)

End Sub
```

The checkboxes update in the UI as expected (cb3 immediately appears checked when cb1 and cb2 are checked, and unchecks if either 1 or 2 are unchecked), but when I save their values back to the database cb3's state in the code behind has not changed.  cb1 and cb2, which never have their state changed by this script, always have the expected state when saved to the database.  cb3 is always the same state as was uploaded from the database and it appears the java script does not update cb3.Checked for the code behind.  Of course I need to save the expected values for all checkboxes to the database and I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to expose the state of this checkbox to the vb.net code behind.

I've tried moving the script's code to the code behind using a CheckedChanged handler but that is painfully slow, hence why I'm using the java script to update cb3

Comment: the checkbox is not enabled, so it will not be updated

Comment: @nbk you're right, when I enable cb3 the correct state is saved to the database.  Why then is the UI updated with the proper check state when it is disabled?

Comment: I think that someone made a mistake and you will find lots of such inconsistência.